# Apply new Locale to application when changed from PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity

My preferences are setup via `PreferenceActivity` which in `onBuildHeaders()` loads the `PreferenceFragments` from `<preference-headers>` xml resource.

One of those fragments holds a `ListPreference` with languages.

`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` is correctly (un)registered and `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` is correctly called. When the `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` is called, first I update the default locale:

```
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    mContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

then I update titles and summaries of preferences of this fragment (which correctly pull strings from newly set locale).

Going back triggers `onResume` in `PreferenceActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    invalidateHeaders();
}
```

which forces preference fragments to correctly display their titles in newly set locale.

All that is fine, but what troubles me is that:

- `PreferenceFragment` title is not changed
- `PreferenceActivity` title is not changed
- all text of MainActivity remains unchanged (until the activity is re-created by e.g. screen rotation)

How can I fix that?

*(minSdkVersion is 15)*

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. Here are all the aspects...

### 1) `PreferenceFragment` title is not changed

When updating title and summaries in `PreferenceFragment` also update `PreferenceActivity` title (which actually provides title for the `PreferenceFragment`):

```
getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_settings));
```

### 2) `PreferenceActivity` title is not changed

In `onResume()` of the `PreferenceActivity`, update its title:

```
setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_settings));
```

### 3) all text of MainActivity remains unchanged

Track locale (String) in `onCreate()` of MainActivity and compare it to current locale (String) in `onResume()`. If different, restart the activity with:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```